# overhead of critical region exceeds speedup of for loop parallelization

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to parallelize the following serial code in a function

```
    float arr[100];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) arr[i]=0;

    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      float* pi = arr+i;
      int index[10];
      f(i, index); // f fills in the array index
      for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        float* pj = arr+index[j];
        if (pj > pi){
            float tmp = g(i,j); // some function g
            *pi += tmp;
            *pj += tmp;
        }
      }
    }
```

and a similar one appear in another function

```
    float arr[100];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) arr[i]=0;

    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      float* pi = arr+i;
      int index[10];
      f(i, index); // f fills in the array index
      for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        float* pj = arr+index[j];
        if (pj > pi){    
            h(pi,i); // function h updates the memory pointed by pi, 
            // by adding to  to *pi something, which only depends on i but not on the values pointed by pi.
            h(pj,j); // 
        }
      }
    }
```

My way is:

```
    float arr[100];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) arr[i]=0;

    int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(arr) private(i,j) schedule(auto)
    for ( i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      float* pi = arr+i;
      int index[10];
      f(i, index);
      for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        float* pj = arr+index[j];
        if (pj > pi){
            float tmp = g(i,j);
            *pi += tmp;
            #pragma omp atomic update
            *pj += tmp;
        }
      }
    }
```

and

```
    float arr[100];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) arr[i]=0;

    int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(arr) private(i,j) schedule(auto)
    for ( i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      float* pi = arr+i;
      int index[10];
      f(i, index);
      for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        float* pj = arr+index[j];
        if (pj > pi){
           h(pi,i); 
           #pragma omp critical (pj)
           h(pj,j); // 
        }
      }
    }
```

I use the atomic and critical directives because multiple threads can write to memory pointed by pj simultaneously. (if I am correct, threads don't write to the memory pointed by pi simultaneously.)

However, adding the atomic and critical directives, increases the running time to be around the same as that of the serial code.

So I wonder what should I do?

Comment: try to parallelize well outside this algorithm. is that the whole program?

Comment: I'm thinking you are blocking on the writes.  Perhaps create a summer for each thread and then sum the sums are the end.

Comment: @SteveCox: this for-loop being parallelized is already the outmost loop.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks! can you be more specific about how to create a summer for each thread and then sum the sums are the end? Note the function `h`.

Comment: just for my own personal curiosity, exactly what does `f` fill `index` with?

Comment: The indices of the neighbors of the entity associated with `i`. @SteveCox

Comment: are the neighbors bidirectional? if pi has neighbor pj, does pj have neighbor pi? (im sort of assuming it does based off of `pj > pi`)

Comment: yes, symmetric. @SteveCox

Comment: okay, so you are running once per relation, is there a reason you couldn't break the algorithm up so it only does one side of the computation (only ever touching pi) but repeats it for both sides of the iteration, so you don't need to worry about locking the memory. you would have to compute g(i,j) twice, and i can't really tell how costly that is. you would also avoid the branch from the condition inside the innermost loop

Comment: @Steve Yes, the purpose of `pj>pi` is to compute `g(i,j)` once, and it can be costly, and more than having the branch from the condition is.

Comment: okay great, then why don't we memoize `g(i,j)` in a 100x10 array to avoid that computation. That can definitely be done in parallel easily

Comment: wait is that supposed to be `g(i,j)` or `g(i,index[j])` the second one seems a lot more likely to me

Comment: @SteveCox: the second one, I tried to simplify my post too much.

Comment: okay well, without question, the second algorithm can be easily rewritten to not need any critical region, just remove the condition and the write to pj so that it runs straight through. unless that was also over simplified.

Answer (score 1):

The entire idea of parallelizing this code is flawed. There is simply not enough work to justify the overhead of starting and synchronizing the threads.

With the atomic updates, the overhead of the synchronization itself is not too bad, but the critical section *will* destroy all performance: Only one thread can enter it at a time, and typical overhead times for synchronization are on the order of microseconds (depending on how the waiting is implemented). This is *much worse* than just doing the work with one core.

If you are absolutely set on parallelizing (I am not going to use the word "optimizing" here) the loop that calls `h()`, you should make sure that `h()` operates in a thread-safe manner (probably using atomic operations), and forget about the `#pragma omp critical`.